# How to implement `ssize_t` in c++ complier correctly?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++ and I saw there was a line of codes writing on the textbook:

```
ssize_t num = index; // index could be -1 in the example of my textbook`
```

The `num` is a variable to contain the index return from a traversing. However,after I copy this code to my C++ compiler, it says it can not find the definition of `ssize_t`. And I can hardly find there is any definitions about `ssize_t` in C++. I saw that it could be use in C but not C++. Right?

Comment: That data type identifier isn't built into either C or C++, both of them need the correct #include.

Comment: `#include <sys/types.h>` (probably, at least on every POSIX system I've ever worked on).

Comment: @WhozCraig: The [official POSIX aka Single Unix Specification agrees](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html)

Comment: If you want a standard drop-in (most likely) replacement for `ssize_t` you could use [`std::ptrdiff_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) which is what [`std::ssize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) and [`ranges::ssize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/ssize) returns. It is _"used for pointer arithmetic **and array indexing, if negative values are possible**_"

Comment: Sorry for explain my question not clearly enough, I edited my question again. `num` is for index, which could be -1 or positive index. I just try to change it to `size_t` but I think it is not suitable because `size_t` could not be negative.

Comment: It cannot find the definition because you didn't #include the right file.  Add `#include <sys/types.h>` and it will find the definition (if you are on a POSIX platform or any other platform that has a `sys/types.h`).  If you need portability to all C and C++, not only POSIX, use `ptrdiff_t` as @TedLyngmo suggested.  That also needs a `#include <stddef.h>` to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssize_t` can (and cannot) be used in C++ just as much as it can (and cannot) be used in C. There is no fundamental type by such name in either language, and there is no `ssize_t` type in the ISO C standard library, nor is there a `std::ssize_t` in the C++ standard library.

`ssize_t` is defined in the POSIX standard. If your program is compiled for a POSIX system, then you can use `ssize_t` by including the header from the POSIX library that defines it. On non POSIX system, such header doesn't exist, so this is not portable. You shouldn't use `ssize_t` in a cross platform program except in a POSIX specific module that uses the POSIX API.

When you aren't using the POSIX API, you can typically substitute `ssize_t` with `std::ptrdiff_t`.